How to properly zoom and update OpenStreetMap tiles on my JS Maps
When I launch the file everything works fine and the mouse movements are correct however the zoom is catastrophic and it does not zoom/refresh the next tiles of OpenStreetMap
class CustomMap {
    constructor(containerId) {
      this.container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  
      if (!this.container) {
        console.error(`Element with ID '${containerId}' not found.`);
        return;
      }
  
      this.tileContainer = document.createElement('div');
      this.tileContainer.classList.add('tile-container');
      this.container.appendChild(this.tileContainer);
  
      this.zoomLevels = [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; // Niveaux de zoom disponibles
      this.zoomIndex = 2; // Index du niveau de zoom initial
      this.tileSize = 256; // Taille d'une tuile
      this.center = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // Centre initial de la carte
      this.tiles = {}; // Pour stocker les tuiles chargées
  
      this.initMap();
      this.enableDrag();
      this.enableZoom();
    }
  
    initMap() {
      this.updateTiles();
    }
  
    updateTiles() {
      const zoomLevel = this.zoomLevels[this.zoomIndex];
      const tilesInViewportX = Math.ceil(this.container.offsetWidth / this.tileSize);
      const tilesInViewportY = Math.ceil(this.container.offsetHeight / this.tileSize);
  
      const startX = Math.max(0, Math.floor(this.center.x - tilesInViewportX / 2));
      const startY = Math.max(0, Math.floor(this.center.y - tilesInViewportY / 2));
      const endX = startX + tilesInViewportX;
      const endY = startY + tilesInViewportY;
  
      // Supprimer les tuiles qui ne sont plus visibles
      for (let key in this.tiles) {
        const tilePos = key.split('_').map(Number);
        if (tilePos[0] < startX || tilePos[0] >= endX || tilePos[1] < startY || tilePos[1] >= endY) {
          this.tiles[key].remove();
          delete this.tiles[key];
        }
      }
  
      // Ajouter les tuiles manquantes
      for (let x = startX; x < endX; x++) {
        for (let y = startY; y < endY; y++) {
          const key = `${x}_${y}`;
          if (!this.tiles[key]) {
            const tile = document.createElement('img');
            tile.classList.add('tile');
            tile.src = `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${zoomLevel}/${x}/${y}.png`;
            tile.style.width = `${this.tileSize}px`;
            tile.style.height = `${this.tileSize}px`;
            tile.style.position = 'absolute';
            tile.style.left = `${(x - startX) * this.tileSize}px`;
            tile.style.top = `${(y - startY) * this.tileSize}px`;
            this.tiles[key] = tile;
            this.tileContainer.appendChild(tile);
          }
        }
      }
  
      // Déplacer le conteneur de tuiles pour simuler le déplacement de la carte
      this.tileContainer.style.transform = `translate(${-(this.center.x % 1) * this.tileSize}px, ${-(this.center.y % 1) * this.tileSize}px)`;
    }
  
    enableDrag() {
      let isDragging = false;
      let startX, startY;
      let startCenterX, startCenterY;
  
      this.container.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
        if (event.button !== 0) return; // Ne rien faire si ce n'est pas le clic gauche
        event.preventDefault();
        isDragging = true;
        startX = event.clientX;
        startY = event.clientY;
        startCenterX = this.center.x;
        startCenterY = this.center.y;
        this.container.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
      });
  
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        isDragging = false;
        this.container.style.cursor = 'grab';
      });
  
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        if (isDragging) {
          const deltaX = (event.clientX - startX) / this.tileSize / this.zoomLevels[this.zoomIndex];
          const deltaY = (event.clientY - startY) / this.tileSize / this.zoomLevels[this.zoomIndex];
  
          this.center.x = startCenterX - deltaX;
          this.center.y = startCenterY - deltaY;
  
          this.updateTiles();
        }
      });
  
      // Désactiver le défilement de la page lors du déplacement de la carte
      this.container.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => event.preventDefault());
    }
  
    enableZoom() {
      this.container.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
  
        const rect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
        const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
  
        const oldZoomIndex = this.zoomIndex;
        const zoomDelta = event.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
        this.zoomIndex += zoomDelta;
        this.zoomIndex = Math.min(Math.max(this.zoomIndex, 0), this.zoomLevels.length - 1);
  
        // Calculer les facteurs de zoom
        const oldZoomFactor = this.zoomLevels[oldZoomIndex];
        const newZoomFactor = this.zoomLevels[this.zoomIndex];
  
        // Calculer le déplacement relatif du centre de la carte
        const deltaX = (mouseX - rect.width / 2) / this.tileSize / oldZoomFactor;
        const deltaY = (mouseY - rect.height / 2) / this.tileSize / oldZoomFactor;
  
        // Mettre à jour le centre de la carte
        this.center.x += deltaX * (oldZoomFactor - newZoomFactor);
        this.center.y += deltaY * (oldZoomFactor - newZoomFactor);
  
        // Mettre à jour les tuiles
        this.updateTiles();
      });
    }
  }
  
  // Utilisation de la bibliothèque
  const customMap = new CustomMap('mapContainer');

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ma Carte</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script src="searchAreaMap.js"></script>
  <script>
    const customMap = new CustomMap('mapContainer');
  </script>
</body>
</html>


It should zoom perfectly where the mouse cursor is and the tiles should update when I zoom (a bit like if you zoom in on your house on Google Maps for example) I tried different corrections in the JS and SAME CHATGPT!
